# Alamofire NetworkActivityIndicatorManager Swift3 branch error

Tags: alamofire

/Users/jo.bloggs/Development/projName/projName/Pods/AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator/Source/NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.swift:25:8: Module file's minimum deployment target is ios9.0 v9.0: /Users/jo.bloggs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projName-gssqurpxvfvyqyfpzbuoqcksofwl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire/Alamofire.framework/Modules/Alamofire.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule

My podfile has this at the top

platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

All my targets have ios 10 as Deployment Target.

I deleted DerivedData, cleaned and rebuilt

I deintegrated cleaned and installed pods

Still stuck on this error

Can anybody please help me?

Thank you

Comment: >>All my targets have ios 10 as Deployment Target.
Not true .... I missed some :-(     I had a setting of 8 on two frameworks.  Changing these to 10 fixed my issue